# Is there an efficiency problem with my query to select middle rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, query-optimization

I am trying to select rows 3 - 5 of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Finance_User 
ORDER BY email DESC
```

I originally had just:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY email DESC) AS RowNum, * 
FROM 
    Finance_User 
WHERE 
    RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 5
```

But this did not work as `RowNum` was an invalid column.

Instead I did the below:

```
WITH OrderedUsers AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY email DESC) AS RowNum, * 
    FROM 
        Finance_User
)
SELECT *  
FROM OrderedUsers 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 5
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I am concerned that there might be performance issues with this as it seems to be selecting from the table twice?

Comment: "seems to be selecting from the table twice". No it isnt. Look at the execution plan. you will see one scan on the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER()` with a CTE (or a subquery) won't scan the table twice. However using the window function might incur additional processing for the RDBMS.

You could achieve the same results with [`ORDER BY ... OFFSET ... FETCH ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), available starting SQL-Server 2012, that are provided specifically for the purpose of paging a resultset:

```
SELECT *
FROM Finance_User
ORDER BY email DESC
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

From the documentation:

> We recommend that you use the OFFSET and FETCH clauses instead of the TOP clause to implement a query paging solution and limit the number of rows sent to a client application.

Comment: I have compared the execution plan of this query to mine and the execution plan is shorter. Just thought that'd be worth mentioning.

Comment: @AugustWilliams: that's good to know indeed...By *shorter*, do you mean *less expensive* ?

Comment: There are three extra items in the execution plan for my query - filter, sequence and segment. All of these have 0% cost, the same as your query. Perhaps this is down to lack of data? As the difference in execution plan affects items with only 0% cost, I assume in this context its neither an improvement nor unimprovement.

Comment: yep the `offset ... fetch` collapses the work of numbering the rows and filtering into a single `TOP` operator but basically they still do the same thing of reading a sorted stream and picking out the ones in the desired range so any difference will be extremely marginal. Except for the cardinality estimates are better in the `offset..fetch` case so this may improve other parts of the plan (estimated 5 going into the `TOP` vs estimated 100 - though 5 is actual in both cases)

Comment: @AugustWilliams: so basically it looks like `OFFSET ... FETCH` is more of a syntax shortcut, that relies on something equivalent as `ROW_NUMBER()` behind the hood, but does not actually optimize more. Given the fact that window functions are (supposely) highly optimized already, I find this result quite logical after all...

Comment: The better cardinality estimates may help though. If I use `sys.objects ORDER BY name DESC` the difference in the `TOP 100` vs `TOP 5` estimate makes a difference between it choosing a plan processing the first 5 in index order with lookups and a plan sorting the whole table

Answer (score 3):

Your query is fine. 
`WITH AS` clause is a [Common Table Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) which means that this query may be reused later and should be cached if needed and possible. So there should not be any problem with "selecting from the table twice".

The same result you can get with this query:

```
SELECT * from 
   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY email DESC) AS RowNum, * FROM Finance_User) 
where RowNum between 3 and 5
```

And finally, you can always check execution plan and make sure of it as well.